# MaterialUI -withStyles hoc causes <Select /> menu to close when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

### Current Behavior

When using the `<Select />` component with `multiple`, the user should be able to select multiple options **without** the menu closing. This works as expected when instancing the `<Select />` component, but when using it with the `withStyles()` HOC, it closes automatically.

#### Demo:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8508891/93466086-fb93ec80-f8eb-11ea-8f81-89443085eabe.gif

```js
// Here we use the HOC and this is where it breaks.
const NewSelect = (props) => {
  const StyledSelect = withStyles({
    // styles etc
}, { name: "NewSelect" })(Select);

  return <StyledSelect {...props} />;
};

// Closes when item selected
<NewSelect multiple { ... } />

// Doesn't close (desired behavior)
<Select multiple { ... } />
```

### Expected Behavior

When using the `withStyles()` HOC, the wrapped Select should behave the same.

### Steps to Reproduce

See Sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-38rhd?file=/demo.js

### Context

We have a design system that is using a few MUI components under the hood; so to hook into our theme we are using `withStyles()` to wrap the Mui component and apply specific styles from our theme.

## Environment

| Tech        | Version |
| ----------- | ------- |
| Material-UI | v5.0.0-alpha  |
| React       |  16.13.1     |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `StyledSelect` declaration outside of `Select2`, because everytime input change, causes `Select2` to be rerendered (I put an `console.log` in there for you to see clearly), StyledSelect is declared again, which cause your unexpeceted behavior

Solution

```
const StyledSelect = withStyles({})(Select);

const Select2 = (props) => {
  console.log("rerender");
  // If we chance StyledSelect to Select (Mui one), it works fine.
  return <StyledSelect {...props}>{props.children}</StyledSelect>;
};
```

Demo

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks! i need to also pass props into the object of the first paramater in withStyles though. Have tried to turn it into an arrow function but am getting 'Objects are not valid as a React child". :(

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-res5e?file=/demo.js

Comment: @LucasArundell cool, I've never notice that way before, a TIL